# What is the voltage between Vin & GND?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have NodeMCU ESP8266N Lolin V3, my 5V relay is powered from Vin of the NodeMCU.
The NodeMCU is powered from 5V USB.

My difficulty is when I measure voltage between Vin & GND, it is of 1.9V, but supposed to be around 5V as it is directly attached with usb 5V supply. Actually my relay is not working with the power tapped from Vin, but relay's led & NodeMCU  led are blinking but relay coil does not trip.
Please confirm is my NodeMCU having problems as voltage between vin & GND read 1.9V.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z6jYX4sCLmRxnWbtBYZCNW6LpckokaC9/view?usp=drivesdk
[image]

Comment: V**in** ... the **in** is the clue - I wouldn't use it as a V**out**

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51873/nodemcu-vin-pin-as-5v-output - there is an answer there that suggests using the `VV` pin for your requirements ... however, don't be surprised if your setup is unstable, due to the power requirements of the NodeMCU and the Relay

Comment: I afraid you could not understand, i m not going to use vin as output similar to digital output of GPIO pin, i am just taking input 5v from Vin to power my relay. There in my image, i have given digital output as D4  to relay in1 from nodmcu D4 pin, but relay's coil not get trip but led blinks for both relay & nodmcu. Found no solution anywhere

Comment: Yeah sorry but there was info in that questions answers that seemed relevant .. i.e. regarding voltage

Comment: Vin does not provide enough current to operate a relay ..... Vin is an input to a voltage regulator .... the voltage regulator cannot be used in reverse

Comment: on some nodemcu boards, apparently, Vin is **directly** connected to USB +5 @jsotola - however, I think there's about as many "NodeMCU" variations as there are stars in the sky ... I have two different types, neither of which have a `VV` pin ... so that's 3 different NodeMCU boards referenced in one sentence :p

Comment: @SumitRoy - you have a Lolin V3 board - I can tell that because below A0 you have GND and VV instead of Rsv and Rsv - VV is "V USB Power output" ... use that with a decent USB power supply (not from a PC as that probably wont supply enough current) ... as I mentioned 5 hours ago ... **USE VV**

Comment: Sorry ... it's **VU** ... not VV ... I'm old and my back is blind and my eyes are bent :p

Comment: Lolin is former Wemos not NodeMcu

Comment: Ooo, I know!  All my CH340-based nodeMCU's have a "broken" vin pin, giving only a couple volts. The same pin on all my CP2102-based nodeMCUs (amica) and wemos D1 minis provides about 4.4v (5v in - a diode drop). They work fine with such relay modules. That's why I refuse to buy the CH340-based ESPs anymore, even if they are a lot cheaper... Replace the devkit and it will work fine as-wired, like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage on Vin when you power that board thru USB is not relevant ... Vin is not the pin you are looking for

You clearly have a Lolin NodeMCU (V3) board - the existence of Gnd and VU (looks like VV in your picture!!) between A0 and S3 pins indicates that

In documentaion easily found by searching for Lolin V3 pinout - VU is described a USB power output

[image: Lolin v3 pinout]

Use this pin to connect to JD-VCC on the relays

I've just now successfully done this with a 4 relay board

I would connect (nodemcu -> relay)

- 3V3 to VCC
- VU to JD-VCC
- Gnd to Gnd
- D*n* to IN*m* - i.e. choose a D pin on the NodeMCU and connect to an IN pin on the relay

Comment: Thanks a lot to give me solution from your precious time, sir, i have tried this solution in the morning, but fail, could you pls provide some link or email so that i can post the video i recorded, sir just for sake of confirmation, i just want to mention that i gave power to relay by doing as follows , VV of nodmcu to JD- VCC of relay, G of nodmcu to left-hand side GND of relay , and D4 of nodmcu to in1 of relay, pls tell am i correctly doing connection, thanks in advance

Comment: You need to connect the 3V pin to the VCC pin on the relay board. JD-VCC is just for the relay coils. Vcc is used for the optocouplers which currently don't have power at all, looking at the picture.

Comment: I think the grey wire in the picture probably goes to vcc ... no wait ... that picture is hard to see ... the other issue the OP has is the lack of VCC as you poinbt3ed out @Gerben - that other VCC **can** be 3v3 (I know, because that's how I connected mine)

Comment: Gray goes to IN2. Most of these boards have a jumper between VCC and JD-VCC. But you probably don't want that here. The opto-isolators led could light up if the pin is set to HIGH (3.3V) on the ESP. So the led will see 1.7V across it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z6jYX4sCLmRxnWbtBYZCNW6LpckokaC9/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: pls see the video, also pls guide me the connection of relay & nodmcu with usb charger..pls

Comment: answer edited with suggestions for connections

Comment: Thanks for connection @Jaromanda X , i shall try and let you know. Did u just see the video i posted on the link

Comment: Manyyyyyyy manyyyyyyy manyyyy THANKS A LOT @Jaromanda, I salute you, hats off to you... In this universe, i have tried solution everywhere but you in this forum gave me working solution.         It got worked as per your connection. Thanks once again. i am so happy

Comment: @SumitRoy - no I did not watch the video

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from your pictures but I don't think you have your relay connected properly.

Some problems i see:

- Your esp8266n seems to be a 3 Volt device; it has 3V output pins
- Vin usually feeds a regulator; the +V rail is usually after it
- Your relay needs 5V but you only have 3V for power and signal

You will need a level shifter, and another powersupply to run your relay. You should be able to put 5v into Vin on your ESP and have it be powered, then you will need a level shifter to connect to the IN1 or IN2 of the realy so that you can control it with 3v. And the relay Vcc and GND also connected to the same power supply.

Comment: Sir, could you please get to know that just connecting relay Vcc with 3.3V Vcc of esp8266 , lot of youtube video demonstrates that relay of 5v works even on 3.3 V. Just Google it pls. There is no external power supply required other than tapping power from esp8266 to power relay. Pls let me know what's the voltage between Vin & ground is it 1.9V!

Comment: the voltage on your particular board is what you measure @SumitRoy - when powered thru USB, mine is 4.74 volts **with nothing connected to it** - but none of my nodemcu boards are **Lolin** brand, and neither have a pin labelled `VV` which I suggested you use 5 hours ago - did you try that at all?